# Can AVFoundation be coerced into playing a local .ts file?

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming

Clearly, AVFoundation (and Quicktime X) can demux and play properly encoded `.ts` containers, because `.ts` containers underly HTTPS live streaming.

Short of setting up a local web service to serve the `.m3u8` and associated `.ts` files, I'd really like to be able to either: convince `AVURLAsset` and/or `URLAssetWithURL` to accept a local file `.m3u8` URI as if it were an HTTP URI, or better yet, be able to use `AVQueuePlayer` to load and play a sequence of `.ts` files without jumping through the live streaming hoops.

The reason I'm wanting to do this is that I need to locally generate movie assets on-the-fly in a somewhat piecemeal fashion - the entire asset won't be available at once but will be generated as time goes by. Obviously this lends itself to an `AVQueuePlayer` but for various reasons my asset fragments are packaged in `.ts` containers. All this sounds like it's perfect for "local" live streaming.

I suspect that `URLAssetWithURL` does some qualification of the string passed to it and then sets some properties to signal that it's looking at a live streaming source which in turn tell `AVPlayer`/`AVQueuePlayer` to expect tracks in `.ts` form. It probably sees the HTTP and decides that this is live streaming.

**So my question is:** how would one go about "fooling" AVFoundation into handling a local `.m3u8` file exactly as it does a remote one?

And the bonus question is: Has anyone (and if so how) been able to make an `AVAsset` from a `.ts` file so that the asset will return the status of the asset's tracks (prepare for playback)?

TIA!

Comment: Same exact problem... I haven't found a solution. Sure would be nice since you can feed this to a MPMoviePlayerController and have Airplay.

Comment: Actually, have you found a way to play .ts files without wrapping them in a HTTP live stream? AVAsset and MPMoviePlayerController both fail when I give them local or network .ts files. I can however use local .m3u8s, even .m3u8s that reference other local .m3u8s.

Comment: No joy -- I ended up putting in a tiny HTTP server and that worked fine but haven't found a way to make an asset directly from a .m3u8 or .ts file. We also took a different approach for experimentation and wrote a proprietary (sorry, can't share) demuxer that reduces the .ts to raw h.264 frames which we then decode and present. It works but is fairly resource costly. Next investigation will be to repackage the raw h.264 as a .mp4 and see how expensive that step is.

Comment: I did get this working with local files without an internet connection. You can spin up a HTTP server on the iPhone and then serve the files to the iPhone via localhost. I slightly modified the iPhone HTTP-server project at http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html to serve the ts and playlist files.

Comment: "TIA" in the google dictionary is "Transient ischemic attack", what do you mean with this?

Comment: @Gabe Can you give me a hint how you changed the code to deliver the files. I am trying to build something similar.

Comment: You should be able to use CocoaHttpServer without any modification to serve via localhost.

Comment: @TomBrito TIA expands to Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Gabe Can you write up an answer on how you used a local HTTP server? I think that is the best answer for this question.

Comment: @Tawpie what did you use to decode raw h264 frames after demuxing?

Comment: (very late comment, lots has happened). I did mean thanks in advance, but transient ischemic attack was equally accurate in this situation! @jAckOdE: I would like to, but that company went under and took their code with them. it's been so long I don't even remember what we did...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem was annoying for us too for a long time. We have finally decided to write a tool to convert a list of ts to an mp4 file. It consists in using TSDemux to demux and concatenate videos/audios and then generate a mp4 file with GPAC.

It does really answer your question, but it may be a way to do what you want to do.
This tool is on Github, feel free to try: https://github.com/Keemotion/TS2MP4

Comment: I want to use the library you wrote but the output mp4 file does not have any sound. There is an open github issue (https://github.com/Keemotion/TS2MP4/issues/6) which describes the problem. Would you care to have a look at it? Much appreciated.

Comment: No we haven't fixed it yet and do not have any plan to work on it for now. Feel free to work on it and submit a pull request.

Comment: Does this Library still work properly, I cloned the repo and even the podfile needs to be updated to have a proper workspace? Even, I am getting multiple file errors that doesn't exist like " #include<gpac/download.h "

Comment: It was in 2014, so 6 years ago. This lib is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create AVURLAssets directly from the underlying ts files, and play these directly, very similarly to the way you would play a mov or mp4 file.

There is some overhead for each ts file, so your best bet is to simply cat the files into one large ts file (based on your m3u8's contents), and play that large file.

There are a couple of gotcha's: AVCompositions constructed using ts file based AVAssets are memory hungry, so avoid AVCompositions apart from small files. You cannot use ts file based AVAssets in a reference movie.

Comment: My hevc/ac3 ts `AVURLAssets` don't play. I can't wrap them in `AVCompositions` as they have no `tracks`. Maybe it doesn't like ac3.

Comment: It doesn't work, tested with h264+aac ts file on iOS 13. The error: "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported. ...