# Playing .ts files using AVAsset? -> The media format is not supported

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, mpeg2-ts

I'm working on my final university project and deveolping an application for iOS 5 that demostrates how HTTP Live Streaming protocol works.

The application gets a list of diferent HLS sources to play. They can be player using the internal iOS mechanism: passing the m3u8 directly to a MPMoviePlayerViewController, or using my own player that I'm developing that performs the protocol step by step.

The idea is to demostrate how it works, downloading the .ts files and choosing the correct stream depending of the download speed at this moment.

The first option, the easy one, works perfectly. MPMoviePlayerViewController does the work. However, when I use my own player, I download the .ts file, but when I try to use it in a AVAsset it says me that the media format is not supported? How can it happen? if the system is able to work with a .m3u8 file it means that the system is able to play .ts files.

Can ypu help me please? or give a solution?

Thanks.

There is a similar question: [Can AVFoundation be coerced into playing a local .ts file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642248/can-avfoundation-be-coerced-into-playing-a-local-ts-file)
but the is no answer yet.

PD: Forgive me for my poor English. I whish you can understand me. I'm from Spain and I must improve my English.

Comment: AV != MP, that's why.  MP must be using a different implementation.  Also, why was Matt Galagher's example not enough?

Comment: I tried MPMoviePlayer but it doesn't play .ts files directly. I'm a bit lost with Matt Galabher's example. I tried to code the HTTP Server but I think I lost something, it doesn't work. I've wanted to try something else before still working in that line.

Comment: It worked fine the last time I ran it.  Just check out a fresh copy from github.

Comment: It works! Thank you. But this solution needs to have the http server running. Its a bit messy to have that only to be able to play a video file. Isn't it? Thank you CodaFi for your help! I will going on searching for another solution, but, I'm able to go on with my project. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @CodaFi , where is the github project link ?

Comment: @why [here](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer)

Comment: The nature of HLS content means it centers around HTTP transmission and there is nothing in the protocol mentioning storing or serving it locally. So players don't accomodate that and hence why we need a local HTTP server to play typical iphone HLS streaming content. If you find an elegant way around this I will literally pay you for the solution. But playing .ts files using a .m3u8 playlist means you have to either transcode it to another format that can be played easily or store it as is and use a server to play it locally.